# App Android doesn't work in all the kind of device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, google-play

I developed Android app using Android Studio 2.2, and it works perfectly on my phone (Samsung galaxy j2  android 5.1.1). But when I try to use it from google play in other device (Samsung galaxy s3 android 4.4.4), they say this app is not compatible with this device.

What I should change for the app can work in all versions of Android smartphone?

build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "names.com.name"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `minSdkVersion` to some lower API.

21 is for Android 5.

**minSdkVersion** represent that Android devices which are equal to greater than the specified API can only install that app.

Comment: ok if change minsdkversion to 15 the app can be install in 97% of device ??
     
and if change the minsdkVersion to 15 so the app can work with API level 15 and 16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24 ??

Comment: yes, but you need take care that app is compatible with all API you are allowing. Sometimes in low end devices app crashes

Answer (score 1):

Its because you set the minSdkVersion 21. for that it cannot be installed in lower then 21 sdk versions . Check out [this](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html) link to see the android versions and API levels. If you want to install your app in lower api versions then u have to put that API level in minSdkVersion .

Comment: ok if change minsdkversion to 15 the app can be install in 97% of device ?? 
     
and if change the minsdkVersion to 15 so the app can work with API level 15 and 16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24 ??

Answer (score 0):

The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in `minSdkVersion`  attribute.By targeting `API 15` and later your app will support 97% devices.

Comment: ok if change minsdkversion to 15 the app can be install in 97% of device ??

Comment: and if change the minsdkVersion to 15 so the app can work with API level 15 and 16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24 ??

Comment: Yeah it will work on all devices running above API level 15